# Record an eye blinking waveform signal from EEG signals

Tags: eeg, signal-detection

I want to Record an eye blinking waveform signal from EEG signals , but it need to make a quiscent periods of recording , So how to make this quiescent periods(i.e the signal has a zero amplitude at all time in the quiescent recording except the eye blinking time)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

1. Flatline EEG is how brain death is defined, and while it may be possible to induce an eye blink in a deceased human, I am sure ethics will not approve, and it won't be scientifically satisfactory.
2. even in the case of a real flatline EEG, there will always be some remaining residual activity (albeit very weak), such as line noise.

However,

1. the eye blink is a few orders of magnitude stronger than the ongoing EEG
2. you can isolate eye blink activity using techniques such as [ICA](http://sccn.ucsd.edu/~scott/pdf/CLINPH00.pdf)

Comment: if you read this [paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2860141/pdf/nihms115146.pdf) you will find : "Here we isolated the eye blinking signature from a quiescent period during the recording, and used this signal as the template" , it's seems that i have misunderstand the idea ?

Comment: Perhaps. A quiet period is usually not one where the EEG flatlines, but simply one where not much else is going on, e.g., no significant alpha wave activity, movement of the subject, or epileptic fits. If the purpose of the question is to obtain a template blink to regress out eye activity: don't; use ICA, as in the paper I'm linking to in my answer, which very robustly removes blink and horizontal movement artifacts.